# Why is my Perl test failing incorrectly?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I have created the following testing class:

```
package Test::DB;

# $Id$
#

use strict;
use warnings;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

use Carp;
use English '-no_match_vars';
use Test::Most;

use base 'Test::Class';

sub startup : Tests(startup) {
    eval {
        require esp_libs_db;

        esp_libs_db->import;

        1;
    } or Carp::croak($EVAL_ERROR);

    return 1;
}

sub connect : Tests(2) {
    can_ok 'esp_libs_db', 'espDbConnect';

    my $schema = 'test_schema';

    throws_ok { espDbConnect($schema) }
      qr/Cannot locate database ($schema) connection file./,
      'dies when connection file does not exist';

    return 1;
}

1;
```

When I come to run the test I get the following output:

```
t/run.t ..
#
# Test::DB->connect
1..2
ok 1 - esp_libs_db->can('espDbConnect')
not ok 2 - dies when connection file does not exist

#   Failed test 'dies when connection file does not exist'
#   at t/tests/Test/DB.pm line 39.
#   (in Test::DB->connect)
# expecting: Regexp ((?-xism:Cannot locate database (test_schema) connection file.))
# found: <FONT color=red size=4 face=arial>ERROR: PM_DB_0004: Cannot locate database (test_schema) connection file.</FONT> at t/tests/Test/DB.pm line 38
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/2 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/run.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=2,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.44 usr  0.07 sys +  2.44 cusr  0.43 csys =  3.38 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

I cannot see why the second test is failing when it should quite clearly pass

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(` and `)` are special characters in regular expressions, try escaping them:

```
qr/Cannot locate database \($schema\) connection file./
```